# Where to connect c wire in furnace

Tags: furnace, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I have 5 wires running to the thermostat from the furnace. The blue wire is not connected on either side. I'd like to connect it as my c wire for a smart thermostat.

On the furnace I see W R Y G and what looks like P on the top right. So no C. Am I out of luck or can I connect the C wire elsewhere?

Make and model of furnace: Trane electronic ignition xe 70

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: What make and model is your furnace?

Comment: Trane electronic ignition xe 70

Comment: Can you post a picture of the wiring diagram label on the furnace?

Comment: I feel like I've checked everywhere and can not find it. Back of every panel, in the furnace, around it.

Comment: Strange -- does the transformer have a nameplate label on it at least?

Comment: If the transformer is the device behind the red plate I took a picture of, there's a sticker on there that I added a picture of on the original post. Not sure how helpful that will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The *other* white wire is your clue

See that two-wire cable with the red wire connected to the yellow (Y) wire from the thermostat cable? That cable controls your compressor, and the white wire from it *must* connect to the equivalent of the C terminal on your air handler for your air conditioner to work.  So, connect whatever wire you're going to use as C to the same terminal as that white wire, and you'll be good!

Comment: To be sure: follow the white wire from the black sheath that has just the red and white wire in it, NOT the white wire from the thermostat. Correct?

Comment: @MahoreLee -- correct!